# hibernate удаляет записи в таблице при повторной вставке

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

есть 2 сущности :

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class File {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "file_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "file_generator", sequenceName = "file_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private Integer size;
    private String type;
    private LocalDate createDate;
    private boolean hideInList;
    private String fileName;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", nullable = false,updatable = true,insertable = true)
    private Article article;
}
```

и

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "article_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "article_generator", sequenceName = "article_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    Long id;
    private Long parentId;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String content;
    private String simpleAddress;
    private String linksTitle;
    private String contentTitle;
    private String filesTitle;
    private LocalDate publishDate;
    private String nameColor;
    private Long background;
    private boolean section;
    private Integer template;
    private Integer position;
    private Integer type;
    private Long competitionId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "article", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<File> files;
```

а так же есть метод для добавления статьи и нескольких файлов:

```
   // Создает статью или папку
    public boolean createArticle(ArticleDto dto) {
        Optional<Article> byId = articleRepository.findById(dto.getId());
        if (byId.isPresent()) {
            List<File> collect = dto.getFiles().stream().map(articleMapper::convertFromFileDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Article article = articleMapper.convertFromArticleDto(dto);
            article.setFiles(new ArrayList<>());
            articleRepository.save(article);
            for (File f : collect) {
                f.setArticle(article);
                fileRespository.save(f);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

но когда происходит маппинг в сущности и вставка записи,то добавляемый файл заменяет собой существующий.
Не пойму откуда ноги растут.

```
Hibernate: delete from file where id=?
Hibernate: select nextval ('file_id_seq')
Hibernate: insert into file (article_id, create_date, file_name, hide_in_list, size, title, type, url, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

проблема крылась в `orphanRemoval = true`, убрав её - я решил проблему